# Display problem in the MUI Autocomplete of my form

Tags: css, typescript, next.js, material-ui, tailwind-css

I am new using Material UI and Tailwind CSS, what happens is that in my form, when I have multiple data in my Autocomplete, the input of the Autocomplete overlaps and stays over the next DatePicker. Why is this happening? I leave an image where shows my problem:

[image]

also, I'm gonna leave my code of LfProjectModal.tsx

```
"use client"

import * as React from "react"
import { createProjectFormSchema } from "@/validations/form/projects/createProjectForm"
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod"
import Modal from "@mui/material/Modal"
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form"
import * as z from "zod"

import LfButton from "./LfButton"
import LfDatePicker from "./LfDatePicker"
import LfInput from "./LfInput"
import LfMultiSelectInput from "./LfMultiSelect"
import LfSelectInput from "./LfSingleSelect"

type LfProjectModalProps = {
  open: boolean
  handleClose: React.MouseEventHandler
  image?: string
}

type FormData = z.infer<typeof createProjectFormSchema>

type selectOptionsType = {
  value: string | number
  label: string
}[]

const options = [
  {
    value: 1,
    label: "Branding",
  },
  {
    value: 2,
    label: "Página Web",
  },
  {
    value: 3,
    label: "Tienda Virtual",
  },
  {
    value: 4,
    label: "Trafficker Meta",
  },
  {
    value: 5,
    label: "Trafficker Google",
  },
  {
    value: 6,
    label: "Multimedia",
  },
]

const freelancers = [
  {
    value: "1",
    label: "Erika Giraldo",
  },
  {
    value: "2",
    label: "Mateo Aguirre",
  },
  {
    value: "3",
    label: "Julie Roa",
  },
  {
    value: "4",
    label: "Valentina Loaiza",
  },
  {
    value: "5",
    label: "Bernardo Aguirre",
  },
  {
    value: "6",
    label: "Danna Bucheli",
  },
  {
    value: "7",
    label: "Angie Ruiz",
  },
  {
    value: "8",
    label: "Johana Peña",
  },
  {
    value: "9",
    label: "Claudia Giraldo",
  },
  {
    value: "10",
    label: "Mar Garcia",
  },
]

export default function LfProjectModal({
  open,
  handleClose,
  image,
}: LfProjectModalProps) {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    reset,
    control,
    setValue,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<FormData>({
    resolver: zodResolver(createProjectFormSchema),
  })

  return (
    <div>
      <Modal
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
        component="div"
        className="m-4 max-h-min max-w-md rounded-2xl border-2 border-white-500 bg-black-500 p-8"
      >
        <div>
          <form role="form">
            <div className="mt-4">
              <LfInput
                label="Nombre del proyecto"
                name="proy_nombre"
                register={register}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="mt-4">
              <LfSelectInput
                label="Tipo de proyecto"
                name="proy_tipo"
                register={register}
                options={options}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="mt-4">
              <LfMultiSelectInput
                label="Participantes"
                name="proy_freelancer"
                control={control}
                options={freelancers}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="mt-4">
              <LfDatePicker
                label="Fecha de inicio"
                name="proy_finicio"
                control={control}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="mt-4">
              <LfDatePicker
                label="Fecha de entrega"
                name="proy_ffin"
                control={control}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="mt-4 flex content-center justify-center">
              <LfButton>Crear Proyecto</LfButton>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  )
}
```

And I will also leave my code of LfMultiSelectInput.tsx

```
"use client"

import * as React from "react"
import Autocomplete from "@mui/material/Autocomplete"
import Chip from "@mui/material/Chip"
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField"
import { Control, Controller } from "react-hook-form"

export type MultiSelectInputOptionsProps = {
  label: string
  value: string | number
}

type LfMultiSelectInputProps = {
  label: string
  name: string
  control: Control<any>
  obligatory?: boolean
  options: MultiSelectInputOptionsProps[]
} & Omit<React.ComponentProps<"select">, "name">

export default function LfMultiSelectInput({
  label,
  name,
  control,
  obligatory,
  options,
}: LfMultiSelectInputProps) {
  const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = React.useState<
    MultiSelectInputOptionsProps[]
  >([])

  return (
    <div className="mb-2 min-w-full md:min-w-[220px]">
      <label className="mb-2 block text-base font-medium text-white-500">
        {label}
        {obligatory && (
          <span className="ml-1 text-lg font-semibold text-blue-500">*</span>
        )}
      </label>
      <Controller
        control={control}
        name={name}
        render={({ field: { value, onChange } }) => (
          <React.Fragment>
            <Autocomplete
              className="autocomplete"
              sx={{
                borderRadius: "50px",
                textAlign: "center",
                display: "flex",
              }}
              multiple
              options={options}
              value={selectedOptions}
              onChange={(_, newValue) => {
                setSelectedOptions(newValue)
                onChange(newValue)
              }}
              renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField
                  {...params}
                  variant="outlined"
                  className="block h-12 w-full rounded-full px-3 py-[0.54em] text-base font-medium text-white-500"
                />
              )}
              renderTags={(value, getTagProps) =>
                value.map((option, index) => (
                  <Chip
                    label={option.label}
                    {...getTagProps({ index })}
                    onDelete={() => {
                      const newValue = [...selectedOptions]
                      newValue.splice(index, 1)
                      setSelectedOptions(newValue)
                      onChange(newValue)
                    }}
                    sx={{
                      border: "1px solid white",
                      color: "white",
                      "& .MuiChip-deleteIcon": {
                        color: "white",
                        "&:hover": {
                          color: "#02afef",
                        },
                      },
                    }}
                  />
                ))
              }
            />
          </React.Fragment>
        )}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Thanks to everyone who can help me!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue you were facing with the Autocomplete component overlapping the DatePicker has been resolved successfully. Here's a brief explanation of the solution:

The problem arose because the Autocomplete component was rendering Chips that overlapped with the DatePicker. To fix this, I introduced a `Box` component from Material-UI to wrap the `Chip` components. This `Box` is configured with specific styles, such as `display: flex`, `flexWrap: no-wrap`, and `gap: 0.5`, to ensure that the Chips are positioned correctly and don't overlap with other elements.

Here's the modified code snippet:

```
<Box
  sx={{
    display: "flex",
    flexWrap: "no-wrap",
    gap: 0.5,
    position: "relative",
  }}
>
  {/* ... map and render Chip components here */}
</Box>
```